# Realize the given system in cascade form of 2nd order section in signal flow graph representation(with complex exponents)?

Tags: filters, transfer-function, control-systems

[image]

I know how to solve cascade form for normal case, but I don't know how to solve cascade form if I get complex exponentials. How do I solve this? Can you provide me 1 solved example or some hint or some idea.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13vGHn5G32i4J7sqlbf715yq6DNbrbB56/view?usp=sharing

Here is what I have solved.

Comment: What is a "normal" case for you ? What have you tried and where are you stuck? Looks like homework

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13vGHn5G32i4J7sqlbf715yq6DNbrbB56/view?usp=sharing I have done these much. My confusion is only due to cosjnpi/3+jsinjnpi/3...what should i do to that?

Comment: [LaTeX](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1722/50076)

Comment: Hint: the zeroes and poles come in complex conjugated pairs.

Answer (score 1):

@Hilmar, I solved this question. I am the OP. I forgot the password of my old account. Poles are not in complex conjugated pairs. The solution is simple. It uses this formula.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just make separate transfer functins as h1(z) ..h4(z) and multiply matching pair which cancels the exponent term.

Comment: Please don't make the contents of your question an image.  Also, it it unclear what you need help with, this appears to be homework.